# User Stories in Microsoft DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I have the free version of Microsoft DevOps and want to create a User Story in a current sprint. Is this possible or do I need to pay for a version that supports this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the comparison of "free" vs. "paid" versions: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services.  You can create user stories in either case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/create-your-backlog?view=azure-devops

Comment: Did you read the documentation before asking this question?

Comment: How do I create a new user story? +new work item only shows 3 options. Task, Issue, and Epic.

Answer (score 0):

There is an abundance of documentation for [getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/sign-up-invite-teammates?view=azure-devops#create-a-project) in Azure DevOps Services.

The short answer is: no, you do not need to pay for the ability to create user stories.

You're seeing those options because you're still using the **[Basic Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/what-is-azure-boards?view=azure-devops&tabs=basic-process#work-item-types)** and not the **[Agile Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/what-is-azure-boards?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#work-item-types)**. [Change the process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops#change-the-process-used-by-a-project) for your project to use the agile work item types and workflow.

[image: Click Me]